# How to make JavaScript recognize backspace?

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have javascript that is working and doing what I want but with one key thing missing.
basically when the user fills in the form 2 fields are disabled.

```
<label>Can you drive? </label> <input type="booleam" id="drive" disabled><br>
<label>What is your occupation? </label> <input type="text" id="occupation" disabled><br>
```

the function sees what value is typed into the age field and then depending on what it is will disable 1 or both fields. currently if you type in say '50' the fields are enabled. great. but if you then delete the zero so i have '5' the fields will still remain enabled. 
i want it to be ultra responsive so that it can respond in real time to any alterations to user input. is this possible?

```js
function ifOfAge(){

 var age = document.getElementById("age");
 var drive = document.getElementById("drive");
 var occupation = document.getElementById("occupation");
 
 if (age.value >=21){
  drive.disabled = false;
  occupation.disabled = false;
 }else if (age.value >=16){
  drive.disabled = false;
    }
  
 
 
}
```

```html
<form id="myform">
  
  <label>Username </label> <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Username must be unique" class="mytooltip"><br>
  
  <div class="pwordCheck">
   <label>Password </label> <input type="password" id="pword" data-placement="bottom" title="" onkeyup="passwordValidation(); return false;" data-original-title="Password must be more than 6 characters long" class="mytooltip"><br>
   <label>Confirm Password </label>  <input type="password" id="confpword"  onkeyup="passwordValidation(); return false;" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Passwords must match" class="mytooltip">
   <span id="themessage" class="themessage"></span><br> 
  </div>
  
  <label>Email </label> <input type="email" id="e-mail"><br>
  
  <label>Age </label> <input type="number" id="age" onkeyup="ifOfAge(); return false;"><br>
  
  <label>Can you drive? </label> <input type="booleam" id="drive" disabled><br>
  
  <label>What is your occupation? </label> <input type="text" id="occupation" disabled><br>
  
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="usernameAlreadyExists(); return false;">
 </form>
```

Comment: Any code related to your question must be **in** your question, not linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. If the question doesn't make sense and can't be answered without the link, it's not appropriate for this site. Instead, put the [**minimum** complete example](/help/mcve) in the question (and for HTML/CSS/JS questions, that can be a Stack Snippet [the `<>` button] for a live version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onkeyup` doesn't work when you click backspace for example. That causes your code not to work on the change of the input. You can use the [`oninput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/oninput) event instead. It will fire even when you click backspace or do a copy/paste.

```js
function ifOfAge() {

  var age = document.getElementById("age");
  var drive = document.getElementById("drive");
  var occupation = document.getElementById("occupation");

  if (age.value >= 21) {
    drive.disabled = false;
    occupation.disabled = false;
  } else if (age.value >= 16) {
    drive.disabled = false;
  } else {
    drive.disabled = true;
    occupation.disabled = true;
  }


}
```

```html
<form id="myform">

  <label>Username</label>
  <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Username must be unique" class="mytooltip">
  <br>

  <div class="pwordCheck">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="pword" data-placement="bottom" title="" onkeyup="passwordValidation(); return false;" data-original-title="Password must be more than 6 characters long" class="mytooltip">
    <br>
    <label>Confirm Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="confpword" onkeyup="passwordValidation(); return false;" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Passwords must match" class="mytooltip">
    <span id="themessage" class="themessage"></span>
    <br>
  </div>

  <label>Email</label>
  <input type="email" id="e-mail">
  <br>

  <label>Age</label>
  <input type="number" id="age" oninput="ifOfAge(); return false;">
  <br>

  <label>Can you drive?</label>
  <input type="booleam" id="drive" disabled>
  <br>

  <label>What is your occupation?</label>
  <input type="text" id="occupation" disabled>
  <br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="usernameAlreadyExists(); return false;">
</form>
```

Comment: No need to retrieve the DOM elements every time, that will inhibit performance. Get them once, store them in a variable for future use.

Comment: ok this looks good. working for you, not for me, however. for some reason the `oninput` is not turning red when i type it in. old version of JS or something?

Comment: Okay, and if you paste that in your own solution? Does it still work?

Comment: im confused as to why oninput is not turning red in my text editor like the other events (e.g. onclick()) do

Comment: Maybe your editor is broken. Not sure, but if it works, it works.

Comment: ok i was doing something stupid. it now works. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Use the `oninput` event instead.
Also you should re-disable when the age is not greater than 16, or 21. See this updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bpjmzxny/.